# Round only a specific row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table, format, rounding

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                    mpg  cyl   disp     hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4         21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.875
Datsun 710        22.80 4.00 108.00  93.00 3.85 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive    21.40 6.00 258.00 110.00 3.08 3.215
Hornet Sportabout 18.70 8.00 360.00 175.00 3.15 3.440
```

I've rounded each value to 2 decimal places:

```
df <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6] %>% 
  format(round(2), nsmall = 2)
```

I want only the last row to be in integer format, I will be presenting them as tables (currently using kable, but I may switch to htmltable or another package if that can be set in one of those)

In this example it doesn't work for the last column, is there a better way to do this also? - that only seems to be an issue with this particular table, however, and not the other ones I am working with.

Comment: It is not possible to have a single row with different type in R (unless these are `list` columns) because types are column wise and not rowwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with transforming your values separated and then add a common type of variable like `character` in order to bind the data again. Here the code using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- mtcars[1:5,1:6] 
#Format
new <- df[-nrow(df),] %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.character(.))) %>%
  bind_rows(
    df[nrow(df),] %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.character(as.integer(.))))
  )
```

Output:

```
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
1   21   6  160 110  3.9  2.62
2   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85  2.32
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215
5   18   8  360 175    3     3
```

Then you can use that output for other actions like html tables.

Comment: It's seems to me that @Undroid is trying to set round for especific rows, not for specific columns

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use this as a workaround?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6] %>% 
  format(round(2), signif(2), nsmall = 2)
df
                    mpg  cyl   disp     hp drat   wt
Mazda RX4         21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.62
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.88
Datsun 710        22.80 4.00 108.00  93.00 3.85 2.32
Hornet 4 Drive    21.40 6.00 258.00 110.00 3.08 3.21
Hornet Sportabout 18.70 8.00 360.00 175.00 3.15 3.44

df[5,] <- as.integer(df[5,])
df
                    mpg  cyl   disp     hp drat   wt
Mazda RX4         21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.62
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.88
Datsun 710        22.80 4.00 108.00  93.00 3.85 2.32
Hornet 4 Drive    21.40 6.00 258.00 110.00 3.08 3.21
Hornet Sportabout    18    8    360    175    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean by

> I want only the last row to be in integer format

is the format of `x` in which `is.integer(x)==TRUE`, then @Duck's solution is a way to go.

However, from the context of your question, it seems that you concern about rounding numbers and about presenting the numbers in a pretty table by using kable or others. So, I might interpret that the `integer format` to be put in the last row of your data frame is the format of 0 decimal place (please correct me if I'm wrong in my interpretation).

If it`s true, I suggest this simple line:

```
df[nrow(df),] <- round(as.numeric(df[nrow(df),]), digits = 0)
df
#                   mpg  cyl   disp     hp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4         21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.00 6.00 160.00 110.00 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710        22.80 4.00 108.00  93.00 3.85 2.320
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.40 6.00 258.00 110.00 3.08 3.215
# Hornet Sportabout    19    8    360    175    3     3
```

The result can be presented by using `kable`

```
kable(df) %>% kable_styling
```

Comment: Perfect, you're right, I did mean integer format, so 0 decimal places.

Comment: Nice if it's right.  The meaning of integer in R in this topic is important to clarify because in R  an `integer` is not identical with `a number with 0 decimal place`. You can check `is.integer(8)` and `is.integer(8L)` .

Comment: Please kindly accept my answer if you find it helpful to solve your problem.